# Datasets of detailed statistics from MMORPGs

Tags: data-request, economics, games

Are there any datasets of MMORPG statistics? I mean detailed "snapshots" of a virtual world that contain parameters of the game, current status of players (items owned, performed actions), internal economy—things typically mentioned by "economics of video games"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question! There are several MMORPG games that provide this type of data, and APIs to others from which you can extract the data.  Check out the following:

- [World of Warcraft APIs](http://blizzard.github.io/api-wow-docs/) on Github with everything from pets to professions extending over players, guilds, and regions
- [League of Legends API](https://developer.riotgames.com/docs/getting-started) (includes game data and assets, champions, items, runes, masteries, summoner spells, and profile icons)
- Eve Online [data access explained](https://developers.eveonline.com/blog/article/nom-nom-tastey-market-data) (market and universe data at a regional level)
- [GuildWars 2 API](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/API) covering recipes, items, and commerce
- And another [179 game APIs](http://www.programmableweb.com/category/games/apis?category=20098) via the Programmable Web

Several of these require registering but seem to be free. Some, like Eve Online, restrict secondary commercial use, but encourage developers, researchers, and others to use the data for co-development or non-commercial use.

Comment: Thanks, Anton. Very interested in what you'll do with it!

Comment: Research on institutions, Jeanne. Virtual worlds have nice properties for studying the real world. I'll update this page if anything comes out.